# How would you find the order of an element in this case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with $|G| = p^2q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with $|N| = p$. Let $x$ be an element of $G$ with $\text{ord}(x) = q$. What is the order of the element $Nx \in G/N$? Prove your response.

Comment: N is the kernel in the homomorphism $\varphi:G\to G/N$, so $Nx=x$ in $G/N$.  The order should still be $q$.  This is a comment because I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $| G / N | = pq$.  Further, note that $x \not\in N$ because $ord(x) = q \nmid p$.  Now Lagrange's theorem implies $ord(Nx) = 1, p, q, \text{ or } pq$.  Since $ord(x) = q$, we see that $(Nx)^q = Nx^q = N$, which implies $ord(Nx) \mid q$.  Since $ord(Nx) \neq 1$ (because $x \not\in N$), we have that $ord(Nx) = q$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** Since $|G|=p^2q$ for distinct primes $p,q$ and $|N|=p$, $N$ a normal subgroup, then $|G/N|=(p^2q)/p=pq$. But then the quotient group $pq$ is cyclic. If $x \in G$ with $|x|=q$, what should $Nx$ be? So then what is the order of $Nx$?

Comment: $Nx$ *is* an element of $G/N$.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, you are correct. I was reading too fast and read $Nx \in G$. I will amend my answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

The order has to divide the order of the (quotient) group, which is $pq.$ It cannot be bigger than than the original order $q,$ and it cannot be $q,$ since $q.$ does not divide $p.$ Therefore, $q.$